# How to proxy whole linux system using a proxy?

Tags: xubuntu, proxy

i have a proxy and i want to connect to it.

i dont have proxy settings on my linux xubuntu 22.04 xfce, so i need an app to do this for me.

i have tried to connect to my proxy and check if its working, i found that my proxy is working using an browser extention.

so i can proxy my browser but i cant proxy whole linux system.

how can i proxy whole linux system?

system info:

`$neofetch`:

```
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              user@linux 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           ---------- 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         OS: Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
    -yddddddddddddddddddddhdddddddy-       Host: X550CC 1.0 
   odddddddddddyshdddddddh`dddd+ydddo      Kernel: 5.15.0-72-generic 
 `yddddddhshdd-   ydddddd+`ddh.:dddddy`    Uptime: 14 hours, 9 mins 
 sddddddy   /d.   :dddddd-:dy`-ddddddds    Packages: 2389 (dpkg), 6 (flatpak),  
:ddddddds    /+   .dddddd`yy`:ddddddddd:   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
sdddddddd`    .    .-:/+ssdyodddddddddds   Resolution: 1366x768 
ddddddddy                  `:ohddddddddd   DE: Xfce 4.16 
dddddddd.                      +dddddddd   WM: Xfwm4 
sddddddy                        ydddddds   WM Theme: ARK-DARK 
:dddddd+                      .oddddddd:   Theme: ARK-DARK [GTK2/3] 
 sdddddo                   ./ydddddddds    Icons: ara-dark [GTK2/3] 
 `yddddd.              `:ohddddddddddy`    Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
   oddddh/`      `.:+shdddddddddddddo      Terminal Font: Noto Mono Bold 10 
    -ydddddhyssyhdddddddddddddddddy-       CPU: Intel i5-3337U (4) @ 2.700GHz 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 610M/710M/810M/8 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           GPU: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Gr 
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              Memory: 2735MiB / 7835MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not particularly clear, and there may not be a *"one size fits all"* answer, because not every program follows the same rules.

You can try exporting the following from `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export http_proxy=http://your-proxy:port
export https_proxy=https://your-proxy:port
```

A slightly more involved/elaborate approach can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/490594/redirect-local-traffic-to-proxy-port-with-iptables/977515#977515).